# Detecting IP/MAC spoofing using iptables

Tags: iptables, ip, mac-address, spoofing

Is there any way to detect IP or MAC address spoofing with iptables?

Comment: Nope ..........

Comment: You can *in advance* enforce a received IP address to match a MAC address, but as you can't prevent a remote system in the LAN to change its MAC address... part of this would need specific settings on the switch to avoid this to happen at will.

Comment: What are you hoping to detect? What does it look like?